# How to get all permutations of elements in a list manually?

Tags: python

I am manually trying to get permutations of all elements in a list.

This is the code I have written.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

def list_forward(lst_lst):
    lst2 =[]
    for lst in lst_lst: 
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            for j in range(len(lst)):
                lst[j],lst[i]=lst[i],lst[j]
                lst2.append(lst[:])
    return lst2

def perm(lst):
    lst2 =[]
    lst2.append(lst[:])
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst[0],lst[i]=lst[i],lst[0]
        lst2.append(lst[:])
    return list_forward(lst2)

l3 = perm(lst)
lset = set([tuple(t) for t in l3])
l4 = [list(t) for t in lset]
print(len(l4))
```

This returns 23 whereas I should be getting 24 unique lists. What am I doing wrong? What I am looking for is guidance to why one of the lists is missing.

Comment: The documentation for [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) has a sample implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just see the code from `itertools.permutations()` which does the same thing.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations